# Spherical codes and their applications

Tags: coding-theory

I am in the middle of preparing a seminar lecture about spherical codes and as the source literature, I started reading “Codes on Euclidean Spheres” by Thomas Ericson and Victor Zinoviev. I really like the subject which leads to this question:

I am looking for application of spherical codes outside of data transmission. Ericson and Zinoviev mentioned in the introduction that Spherical codes have many applications in physics or biology. Other papers support this claim.
But at this moment I only have found a dissertation which has a chapter about their application in Quantum cryptography. As you can see, I am very interested to find more of their application, but I cannot find any.

I hope there might be some people at Mathematics who may know a few papers/articles about applications of spherical codes.

I am very grateful for any help.

Thanks,
Hypertrooper

Comment: I'm not sure, but did you check whether [Conway&Sloane](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4757-2016-7) has anything? I'm afraid I only know of the uses of spherical codes/designs in math and telecommunications.

Answer (score 2):

The [thesis](http://repositorio.unicamp.br/bitstream/REPOSIP/306622/1/Torezzan_Cristiano_D.pdf) by C. Torezzan cites the following references for applications of spherical codes:

Signal transmission:

- Hamkins, J., & Zeger, K. Gaussian source coding with spherical codes. IEEE
  Trans. Inform. Theory 48, 11 (Nov. 2002), 2980–2989.
- Karlof, J. Decoding spherical codes for the gaussian channel. IEEE Trans. Inform.
  Theory 39, 1 (1993), 60–65.

Spherical quantisation:

- Hamkins, J., & Zeger, K. Optimal rate allocation for shape-gain gaussian quantizers. In Proc. IEEE International Symposium on Information Theory (24–29 June
  2001), p. 182.

Numerical evaluation of integrals over spheres:

- McLaren, A. D. Optimal numerical integration on a sphere. Math. Comp. 17
  (1963), 361–383.

Applications in Chemistry:

- Melnyk, T. W., Knop, O., & Smith, W. R. Extremal arrangements of points and
  unit charges on a sphere: equilibrium congurations revisited. Can. J. Chem. 55
  (1977), 1745–1761.

Applications in Architecture and observations in nature:

- Tarnay, T., & Gáspár, Z. Spherical circle-packing in nature, pratice and theory.
  Topologie Structurale 9 (1984), 39–58.

**Edit:** applications are also exemplified (and many references are listed) in the book *Sphere packings, lattices and groups* by J.H. Conway and N.J.A. Sloane,  pp.11-12. Besides pure geometry, they cite number theory, digital communications, chemistry, physics, biology, X-ray tomography, statistical analysis, numerical evaluation of integrals, dual theory/superstring theory.

Some time ago, I came across [this article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8049360) (doi: 10.1109/TMI.2017.2756072), which presents an application in medical imaging.